# What does trademark use limitation mean in open-source licenses?

Tags: trademark

A lot of [open-source licenses](https://choosealicense.com/appendix/) have a limitation on [trademark use](https://choosealicense.com/appendix/#trademark-use), meaning that they "do not grant trademark rights, even though licenses without such a statement probably do not grant any implicit trademark rights."

[image: Trademark use limitation]

But to whom does this limitation apply to? Does it prevent the trademark, such as the name and logo of the project from being used or modified; or does it stop contributors from registering their own trademarks regarding the name and logo of the project (or in other words, to patent the project).

Is there a clearer explanation for the trademark use limitation?

Comment: When you register a trademark you do not patent anything. You trademark it. So in other words to trademark the project. A patent is a completely different thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does it prevent the trademark, such as the name and logo of the project from being used or modified

The *limitation* does not prevent this - but this is because it is the default in law for any names, logos etc which [meet the threshold to count as a trademark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark#Ability_to_register); it it likely that the names and logos of most open source projects do not meet that threshold. What choosealicense is doing here is classifying licenses into two sets:

- Those which make this explicit.
- Those which do not make this explicit and instead rely on the default in law.

Realistically, the difference here is *probably* moot, but if it's something that you have a specific concern on for a specific project, you should take professional advice.

> or does it stop contributors from registering their own trademarks regarding the name and logo of the project?

It is very unlikely that contributors would be able to make a successful trademark claim for the name and/or logo of an open source project. They are, by their very nature, something available "in the commons" and not indicative of a particular relationship. So again, this is not prevented *by the limitation* but instead by the very nature of trademark law.

> or in other words, to patent the project

Patents and trademarks are very different things. Do not confuse the two.

Comment: Assume that the name and logo meet the threshold of distinctiveness to be considered a trademark, are they automatically protected by trademark law, or are they just eligible for registration?

Comment: The UK distinguishes between unregistered and registered trademarks; registered ones receive higher protection. Again, talk to a lawyer in your jurisdiction if you need actual advice.

Comment: THIS.  Basically, the trademark limitation statement is effectively just a clarification that the license is strictly a copyright license and isn't granting permission to use the trademark, something which recipients might be confused about.